# Yahoo API Weather a veces responde, a veces no

Tags: api, http

Buenos días, buenas tardes.
Estoy usando la API de yahoo weather en una aplicación pero tengo un problema.

[Esta es la query que hago para hacer el GET](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22Vigo%20Espa%C3%B1a%20%22))
Quizás te devuelva datos, quizás no, ese es mi problema.
Existe alguna limitación de ip por acceder varias veces en poco tiempo?
En yahoo pone que existe un límite por ip de 2000 peticiones diarias, pero no veo nada más...

Hay que añadirle una api key? Esto tampoco me ha quedado claro.

[Yahoo weather API](https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/)

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahí mismo dice que tienes que añadir un *API Key*, aunque no indica cómo añadirla a la petición (posiblemente explicado en la página donde se pide el *API Key*).

Sin una *Key*, posiblemente esté usando la **por defecto**, lo que implica que te ciñes al límite de 2000 peticiones diarias compartidas con todos los demás que usen la *Key* por defecto.

Comment: Es imposible que sean 2000 compartidas, en todo caso sería 2000 por IP. Sigue siendo un misterio que funcione una vez sí y una vez no

Comment: Cuando es por api key son por key, no por IP. Por ejemplo, tengo varios proyectos de google maps con una sola api key. Cada uno corre en distintos servidores pero el cobro de uso es por 1 sola api key, sino nisiquiera llegaria al limite de uso normal.

Comment: Acabo de crear una cuenta en yahoo, me dieron un client secret y un client ID, estoy tratando de generar un GET con estos datos como parámetros, a ver si funciona!

Comment: Por cierto entendí mal tu respuesta, pensé que decías que eran 2000 públicas para todos los que usamos yahoo XD tienes razón, con la key serán 2000 privadas, pero sin key no entiendo como funciona

Comment: https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/yql?oauth_consumer_key=dj0yJmk9ODNxNnVRUTZjWVI4JmQ9WVdrOWMwSjJkbG8xTkRJbWNHbzlNQS0tJnM9Y29uc3VtZXJzZWNyZXQmeD04NQ--&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1483801173&oauth_nonce=mDHiFt&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=s7gwd5RnBGb1vxaYrP7OhrN8AIM=&q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22Vigo%20Espa%C3%B1a%20%22)


Con API KEY también funciona de forma random :(

Comment: Con que estas haciendo la request? Que respuesta te da cuando "no responde"? Te devuelve vacio? Generalmente igual debiera devolver aunque sea un error como busy o max request reached (en XML claro). Si usas php prueba dumpear cada respuesta asi despues puedes revisar en el log cuales son las respuestas.

Comment: Devuelve count 0, estuve buscando en los foros y parece ser que yahoo anda muy ocupada en vender su compañía 

https://developer.yahoo.com/forums/#/discussion/11869/yql-weather-returning-result-null-half-the-time

Comment: Mi consejo: mientras tenga ese problema yahoo, no hay mucho que puedas hacer, asi que mejor ponlo en un loop y que siga consultando hasta que el resultado sea distinto que cero (o bien se te acaban los request intentandolo o obtienes la info).